# When using the /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<VERSION> url hack to download all related Files, can we rename the zip?

Tags: urlhacking, contentversion, zip

So I've been using the /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ url method to create a button to download all files related to a record.
However I was wondering if there is a way to rename the zip file that gets created for multiple files.
At the moment, it is always called downloaded-content.zip.

Can we set this to another file name?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?